# Can't get data into javascript from HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a registration from. I am trying to validate the form input data using javascript. But in js I can't get the form data. while I tried to see the form data using `console.log()` function it gives `undefined`.

**Here is my form**

```
<form class="cd-signin-modal__form" action="{{ url('/signup') }}" method="POST" id="appointment-form">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
        <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--username cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signup-username" id="name" >Name</label>
        <input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="reg_name">
    </p>

    <p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
        <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--email cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signup-email" id="email">E-mail</label>
        <input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="reg_email">
    </p>

    <p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
        <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--password cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signup-password" id="password">Password</label>
        <input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="signup-password" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="reg_password">
    </p>

    <p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
        <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--password cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signup-password">Role</label>
        <select class="form-control searchField" id="service_id_search" name="reg_role_id">

            <option value=" ">Select One</option>

            @if($_SESSION['role_data'] != null)

                @foreach($_SESSION['role_data'] as $data)    
                    <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->name }}</option>
                @endforeach

            @endif  

        </select>
    </p>

    <p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">

        <button id="signup" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Create account" style="padding: 16px 20px 20px 20px; color: #fff; margin-top:20px;">Create account
        </button>
    </p>
</form>
```

**Here is the scripts**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#signup').click(function(event){

        var name = $('#reg_name').val();
        var email = $('#reg_email').val();
        var password = $('#reg_password').val();
        var role_id = $('#reg_role_id').find(":selected").val();

        console.log(name);
        console.log(email);
        console.log(password);
        console.log(role_id);
    });
});
```

Why it gives `undefined` !!

Anybody help please ?

Comment: There is no `#reg_name`, `#reg_email` and `#reg_password` in your HTML.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory....It is !! Check the `name` attribute for every input filed

Comment: Change `'#reg_name'` etc. to either `'name[reg_name]'` or `'#signup_name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting form fields by ID but your none of your fields have such IDs and it seems that you are confusing input `name` and `id` properties. For example, for field

```
<input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="reg_name">
```

you need to use its ID with jquery # selector and that is `signup-username` not `reg_name`:

```
var name = $('#signup-username').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access your elements by using their name attribute with an id (#) selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#signup').click(function(event){

    var name = $('#signup_username').val();
    var email = $('#signup_email').val();
    var password = $('#signup_password').val();
    var role_id = $('#service_id_search').find(":selected").val();

    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    console.log(role_id);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have an error on the jquery selector.

```
$('#thisIstheIdAtrributeValue');
```

---

```
 $('#signup').click(function(event){

    var name = $('#signup-username').val();
    var email = $('#signup-email').val();
    var password = $('#signup-password').val();
    var role_id = $('#service_id_search').find(":selected").val();

    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    console.log(role_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#signup').click(function(event){

        var name = $('input[name=reg_name]').val();
        var email = $('input[name=reg_email]').val();
        var password = $('input[name=reg_password]').val();
        var role_id = $('input[name=reg_role_id]').find(":selected").val();

        console.log(name);
        console.log(email);
        console.log(password);
        console.log(role_id);
    });
});
```